# Trying to draw two lines in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw two lines in a rgraph,  I had assume it would be a simple case of calling the same code twice, but only my 2nd ever graph seem to get drawn.
(my code is designed to be called from postgres, I have removed the sql code)

The following code should draw two lines on the canvas /tmp/junk, but all I ever seem to get is a red line,  I had hoped to see both red and green.

```
create or replace function doit() returns text as
$$

printf <- function(...)print(sprintf(...))
png('/tmp/junk.png',width=800,height=500)

x=seq(0,40)
x2=seq(0,80,by=2)
y=seq(0,40)
opar <-par(bg="white")
par(new=T)
yrange=range(y)
plot(x=x,y=y);
lines(x=x,y=y,col="green",lty="solid")
points(x=x,y=y,bg="limegreen",pch=23)

par(new=F)
plot(x=x2,y=y);
points(x=x2,y=y,bg="red",pch=23)
lines(x=x2,y=y,col="red",lty="solid")
points(x=x2,y=y,bg="red",pch=23)

title(main='Example one')
dev.off()
print ("done")
$$ LANGUAGE 'plr';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps somewhat paradoxically, you want

```
par(new=T)
```

to plot on top of an existing plot. As the `?par` help page states:

> If set to TRUE, the next high-level plotting command (actually
>   plot.new) should *not clean* the frame before drawing *as if it were
>   on a **new** device*

But that's really just if you use `plot()` a second time. If you take out that second `plot` as well as `par(new)` and just leave in the `lines` and `points` calls, that will draw on top without much trouble.

The only catch is that the limits of the first plot wont change once they are drawn, so if `y2` is outside the range of `y1`, it may not draw properly. So you can explicitly set `ylim=range(y1,y2)` in the plot command.

So, putting that all together I would do

```
png('/tmp/junk.png',width=800,height=500)

x=seq(0,40)
x2=seq(0,80,by=2)
y=seq(0,40)
y2=seq(0,80,by=2) * .2
opar <-par(bg="white")

plot(0,0, type="n", xlim=range(x,x2), ylim=range(y,y2));

lines(x=x,y=y,col="green",lty="solid")
points(x=x,y=y,bg="limegreen",pch=23)

lines(x=x2,y=y2,col="red",lty="solid")
points(x=x2,y=y2,bg="red",pch=23)

title(main='Example one')
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank You!  Next time I shall RTFM again and again